# if condition between lines inside different lists, parse lists for matches, then use cp

Tags: shell-script, scripting, file-copy, pattern-matching

Please, could anybody kindly suggest me how to do?

I have two lists (both with sha1sums and their relative filenames) but formatted differently, here's an example:
**list01.txt**

```
artist'ssomesong.mp3,3f1dfd39e88e00477483dfd578d5284f5490a0a5
hello(previous one).sh,55a5fdde4843fc2f9d9e691cb658b6389d698b22
mymovie [1989, director's cut].mov,4bdee0fc0eb7a3dbc5bbe2b65a02a1f9dc76c443
[etc...]
```

**list02.txt**

```
3f1dfd39e88e00477483dfd578d5284f5490a0a5  /path/to/my new music/album.wav
f77921adf6748f65fe688a5484ed901d4g9932hh  /path/to/movies/[YEAR]/mymovie [1989, director's cut].mov
55a5fdde4843fc2f9d9e691cb658b6389d698b22  /path/to/scripts,regexs/hello(previous one).sh
[etc...]
```

As you can see, the only good entry is for sha1sum `55a5fdde4843fc2f9d9e691cb658b6389d698b22` with filename `hello(previous one).sh` (2nd line in `list01.txt` and 3rd line in `list02.txt`).

Filneames and paths could contain whitespaces and special characters (eg.: ' " [ ] ( ) { } and so on...).
The only thing to be 100% sure is that `list01.txt` is always formatted as `,sha1sum`; and `list02.txt` will always have `sha1sum  /` (two spaces before /).

As in title of this question, I'd like to use a *if-condition* in a bash script which checks both lists for finding matches (TRUE is if **both sha1sum and filename are the same**) and when it finds them, then will copy every occurence using

```
cp $source $destination
source=reads the /path/to/filename from list02.txt
destination=/wherever/i/want/
```

Thanks!

Comment: The shasum matching is the first line, not the third, and the filenames don't match. Please correct that in your question.

Comment: @Quasímodo hey! Thank you for checking. Now lines are fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't payed attention to `both sha1sum and filename are the same` requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- GNU tools are present (non-standard `xargs` and `cp` options, possibly non-working NUL separator in other `awk`'s)
- The length of the hash is always 40 characters long
- There are always two space characters separating hash and file path in `list02.txt`
- No pipe `|` characters are present in both files (otherwise use a different separator)

First step, merge both files:

```
join -t'|' -1 2 \
    <(sed -E 's/,(.{40})$/|\1/' list01.txt | sort -t'|' -k2) \
    <(sed -E 's/(.{40})  /\1|/' list02.txt | sort -t'|' -k1)
```

- First file: substitute separator `,` with `|` and sort the file on the second field
- Second file: substitute separator     (two spaces) with `|` and sort on the first field
- Join the files on the hash field

Output:

```
3f1dfd39e88e00477483dfd578d5284f5490a0a5|artist'ssomesong.mp3|/path/to/my new music/album.wav
55a5fdde4843fc2f9d9e691cb658b6389d698b22|hello(previous one).sh|/path/to/scripts,regexs/hello(previous one).sh
```

Then use `awk` to test if the filename of field2 is present as filename in the last field. If true, print the last 
field with a NUL separator and pipe the result to `xargs` to copy the files to the destination directory.

```
join -t'|' -1 2 \
    <(sed -E 's/,(.{40})$/|\1/' list01.txt | sort -t'|' -k2) \
    <(sed -E 's/(.{40})  /\1|/' list02.txt | sort -t'|' -k1) \
| awk -F '|' '
  {
    fname1=$2; sub(/.*\//, "", fname1) # extract filename1
    fname2=$3; sub(/.*\//, "", fname2) # extract filename2
  }
  fname1 == fname2{ printf $3 "\0" }   # compare filenames, print filepath with NUL separator
' | xargs -r0 cp -n -t /path/to/destination
```

Copy options:

- `-n` don't overwrite existing files
- `-t` target directory

---

As script:

```
#!/bin/bash

join -t'|' -1 2 \
    <(sed -E 's/,(.{40})$/|\1/' "$1" | sort -t'|' -k2) \
    <(sed -E 's/(.{40})  /\1|/' "$2" | sort -t'|' -k1) \
| awk -F '|' '
  {
    fname1=$2; sub(/.*\//, "", fname1) # extract filename1
    fname2=$3; sub(/.*\//, "", fname2) # extract filename2
  }
  fname1 == fname2{ printf $3 "\0" }   # compare filenames, print filepath with NUL separator
' | xargs -r0 cp -n -t "$3"
```

Run it as:

```
./script.sh list1 list2 /path/to/destination
```

Comment: hello! I think your answer's gonna work, but I get no output from `join -t'|' -1 2 \
    <(sed -E 's/,(.{40})$/|\1/' list01.txt | sort -t'|' -k2) \
    <(sed -E 's/(.{40})  /\1|/' list02.txt | sort -t'|' -k1)`. I think could be my fault: I forgot to mention that both paths and filenames have sometimes special characters!! Sorry, my bad! Now I'll edit the original question to fix that...

Comment: I believe you, but your updated example seems to work here, see my updated join output. If there are no pipe characters or newlines it should be okay. Do the `sed` commands work? Do the `sed` commands with `sort` work?

Comment: yup! i forgot to tell you before. Both `sed | sort` commands work fine (also if there are specials characters) if I iusse them using individually per one file. So, this works: `sed -E 's/,(.{40})$/|\1/' blahblah.ext | sort -t'|' -k2 && sed -E 's/(.{40})  /\1|/' blah.ext | sort -t'|' -k1`